# get link post use script 'data:post.url' blogger not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show URLs on my blog with javascript or jQuery, but it did not work.

My code:

```
$('.elementDIV').html("<a href='data:post.url'>Link</a>")
```

How to change it to work?

Comment: is there an element with class `elementDIV`? what error do you get?

Comment: I'm sure that's not the case, because it is intended to `<div class="elementDIV"> </div>`

Comment: where do you run this code. after the div or before it. is jquery loaded when you run the code. because the code is correct.

Comment: I put in the HEAD and jquery div code in the BODY. How should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap your code with `ready` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.elementDIV').html("<a href='data:post.url'>Link</a>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as your script is in the head and the `<div class="elementDIV"> </div>` is in the body. when your code runs, the div hasn't loaded yet and doesn't exist. put your script somewhere after the div. the best place would be before closing the body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.elementDIV').html("<a href='data:post.url'>Link</a>")
</script>
</body>
```